# EntityManager does not load repository using psr-4 namespaces

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm trying to find all the users I have in my database and when I'm trying to get the repository, doctrine mapping fails because it can't find what is looking for.

I have this namespace in my project for my code.

**composer.json**

```
  "autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
      "Olive\\Todo\\" : "src/",
      "Olive\\Todo\\Exceptions\\" : "exceptions/",
      "Olive\\Todo\\Tests\\" : "tests/"
    }
  }
```

It fails when I'm trying to get the repository to find all the users.

**index**

```
/**
 * Get Users array
 *
 * @param EntityManager   $entityManager
 *
 * @return  array
 **/
function findUser( $entityManager )
{
  $ret = [];

  $userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('User');

  return $ret;
}
```

This is the error I got when I'm trying to execute this code.

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: Class 'User'
>   does not exist in
>   /srv/www/simple-project/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:93
>   Stack trace:

And this is the repository itself.

**UserRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace Olive\Todo\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Olive\Todo\User\User;

/**
 * @author  Ismael Moral <jastertdc@gmail.com>
 **/
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  /**
   * Get all users
   *
   * @return  array
   **/
  public function getUser( $maxResults = 50 )
  {
    $dql = "SELECT u FROM user u";

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery( $dql );
    $query->setMaxResults( $maxResults );

    return $query->getResult();
  }
}
```

I think I need to set up some configuration parameters in doctrine in order to load this class.

I import the class at the top of my script, and also I changed the get repository method. And now I have another error.

```
  $userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository( User::Class );
```

This is the new error I got when I applied the change.

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Undefined
>   method 'getUser'. The method name must start with either findBy,
>   findOneBy or countBy! in
>   /srv/www/simple-project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php:238 Stack trace:
>
> 0 /srv/www/simple-project/index.php(78): Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->__call('getUser', Array)
>
> 1 /srv/www/simple-project/index.php(123): findUser(Object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager), Array)
>
> 2 {main}   thrown in **/srv/www/simple-project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php** on line **238**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the namespaced class not the class name. So:

```
$userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository( 'Olive\Todo\User\User' );
```

Also you can use this syntax, if the php have 'imported' it via use which i personally use:

```
$userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository( User::class );
```

Comment: @IsmaelMoral You are using the repository not the entity. Use the entity as I do in my answer.

Comment: I cannot use the method I have in my repository I got an error .

Comment: The repository I get is not the one I did. I think doctrine gaves me a common one.

Comment: Because you have to hint doctrine which one is the repository. Add this decorator on you entity class: ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Olive\Todo\User\UserRepository")

Comment: /**
 * ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Olive\Todo\User\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{

Comment: This is a weird one <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT u FROM User u in /srv/www/simple-project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:43